# What happens to the private key when you ssh from machine C into an ssh tunnel B->A?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, private-key, ssh-tunnel

I have some doubts on what happens to the private keys in my current setup.

**Setup:**

I have 3 machines: A, B, C. A and C don't have public IPs, B has a public IP. I want to access machine A from machine C: A <-- B <-- C.

I have a reverse tunnel connecting A <== B, which is done by running on machine A:

```
ssh [options] -R PORT_B:localhost:PORT_A USER_B@B_PUBLIC_IP -i user_B_private_key.pem
```

So, with this tunnel I can ssh from machine B into machine A using:

```
ssh -p PORT_B USER_A@localhost -i user_A_private_key
```

(Note: I don't use this and I don't have user_A_private_key on machine B)

And with this tunnel I can ssh from machine C into machine A using:

```
ssh -p PORT_B USER_A@localhost -i user_A_private_key
```

**Question:**

I want to know what happens to user_A_private_key on the last case (ssh to A from C using the tunnel A <== B, i.e., ssh on machine C to access machine A through machine B). Machine C is a server and it is safe. Machine B is a sort of Jump Box; it is safe, but I don't want it to know any private keys for security reasons.

Does the key in clear text ever leave machine C? Is user_A_private_key safe in this approach? Is this approach safe and/or recommended?

---

Note: on the SSH Server on machine B I am allowing TCP Forwarding and using GatewayPorts (clientspecified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSH, the private key never leaves the client machine. The servers are getting only the signatures and public key, which proves the possession of the private key.

Comment: When I SSH from C to A using the tunnel B ==> A, C (client) connects to B (server) and does B (client) connects to A (server). So my question remains: is user_A_private_key stored somewhere in machine B in this case?

Comment: what you mean by "known"? No. Private key is never stored on the immediate machine as I already wrote.

Comment: Thank you @Jakuje